# Dart | Flutter: How do I pass a function from a Map under null-safety? Why is a bang operator necessary?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

**Background:**

I have been studying how to pass functions using a Map using dart code. However, I am now stumped. I am getting an unexpected null value from the following code when using DartPad when using null safety:

```
void main() {
Map<String, Function> fruits = Map();
  fruits['apple'] = appleDescription;
  fruits['banana'] = bananaDescription;
  fruits['grape'] = grapeDescription;
  
  exec(fruits['grape']!);
}

void appleDescription() => print('This fruit tastes like red!');
void bananaDescription() => print('This fruit tastes like yellow!');
void grapeDescription() => print('This fruit tastes like purple!');

void exec(Function f) {
    print(f());
}
```

The DartPad Console is shown in the picture below:

[image: screenshot of DartPad after the code is run]

**Questions:**

I reckon that the answer will be easy, but I have been earnestly struggling with this for some time now. My questions are:

1. I expected that only, 'This fruit tastes like purple!' to have been printed in the Console, so I must be missing something here. Am I passing this function correctly from the map, or is there a null-safer way of passing it?
2. I wondered why I must use a bang operator when calling the exec() function. Since I have defined that the fruits map contain <String, Function>, the compiler would understand that it must exist. What am I missing?

Again, thank you in advance for any advice is gratefully accepted from the community.

**Update:**

I used the following code to remove the bang operator with the corrections given in the answer below:

```
void main() {
Map<String, Function> fruits = Map();
  fruits['apple'] = appleDescription;
  fruits['banana'] = bananaDescription;
  fruits['cranberry'] = grapeDescription;
  
  exec(fruits['cranberry']??= (){print('');});
}

void appleDescription() => print('This fruit tastes like red!');
void bananaDescription() => print('This fruit tastes like yellow!');
void grapeDescription() => print('This fruit tastes like purple!');

void exec(Function f) {
    f();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `exec` function tries to print the result of the `f()` function which itselfs prints the phrase you're waiting for.

So basically :

1. the code enters `exec`
2. calls `f()`
3. `f()` prints `This fruit tastes like purple!` and returns `void`
4. the `print` method in `exec` print the return value => null

To summarize, you are printing the return value of a `print` function.

For your code to act as you expect, you should use

```
void exec(Function f) {
    f();
}
```

To reply to your second question, a `Map` can return `null` if you don't pass an existing key to it. That's why you should use the bang, because the return of the `Map` cannot be guaranteed to be non null.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you are absolutely correct. Thank you, Muldec! Also,